# Meteor with flowtype: why does it work?

Tags: meteor, babeljs, flowtype

I imported some legacy code into a new meteor package. I had to adapt many things to make it work, but I was surprised to find that meteor politely ignored all my flowtype annotations, e.g.:

```
GmailApi = class {
  gmail: Object;

  constructor() {
    // HACK(chris): Keep the gmail api instance,
    // to facilitate stubbing it in the test.
    this.gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  }

  /**
   * Sends an email.
   */
  send(email: Email): Promise {
```

It seems that meteor uses babel; babel can remove these annotations, but only with the right options, and I haven't added those.

Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you've added the [`react` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/), it comes with the [`transform-flow-strip-types` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/)